# Как удалённо подключаться к базе данных MS Sql server?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server

Есть база данных на MS Sql Server и есть приложение Win Forms.

Как настроить подключение через приложение к этой базе с разных компьютеров без установки Management Studio на этих компьютерах?

Comment: строка подключения знаете что такое?

Comment: @0xdb в чём смысл правки? SQL Server - это имя СУБД, СУБД - это система управления. Логично говорить - "есть БД **в** СУБД", но никак не **на** СУБД.

Comment: SO платфома не только для того чтобы задать вопрос, но и для того чтобы самостоятельно найти ответ. Эта тема уже не раз обсуждалась, ищите.

Comment: @Anatol Поправте пожалуйста. Я имел ввиду - БД реализованная **на**, и SQL Server - имя продукта.

Comment: Возможно "установка" Management Studio на самом деле является "установкой драйвера субд". Если вам нужен mssql клиент - то его прийдётся ставить.  mssql клиент входит в пакет установки Management Studio, но его можно ставить отдельно.

Answer (score 1):

Используй `System.Data.SqlClient` для подключения к SQL Server. Почитать подробнее можно [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient(v=vs.110).aspx). Удачи)